# Trouble installing power query SDK

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, powerquery

I've installed visual studio community and when trying to install the power query SDK I get an error saying that I don't have the applicable product. Here is the error log.

```
3/31/2022 11:46:11 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
3/31/2022 11:46:11 AM - -------------------------------------------
3/31/2022 11:46:11 AM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
3/31/2022 11:46:11 AM - 17.1.1035-preview2
3/31/2022 11:46:11 AM - -------------------------------------------
3/31/2022 11:46:11 AM - Command line parameters:
3/31/2022 11:46:11 AM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\Brett Evans\Downloads\PowerQuerySdk.vsix
3/31/2022 11:46:11 AM - -------------------------------------------
3/31/2022 11:46:11 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
3/31/2022 11:46:11 AM - -------------------------------------------
3/31/2022 11:46:12 AM - Initializing Install...
3/31/2022 11:46:12 AM - Extension Details...
3/31/2022 11:46:12 AM -     Identifier         : PowerQuerySDK.Microsoft.30831070-f420-4649-a031-6f679996b182
3/31/2022 11:46:12 AM -     Name               : Power Query SDK
3/31/2022 11:46:12 AM -     Author             : Microsoft
3/31/2022 11:46:12 AM -     Version            : 1.0.0.25
3/31/2022 11:46:12 AM -     Description        : A Power Query language service for Visual Studio
3/31/2022 11:46:12 AM -     Locale             : en-US
3/31/2022 11:46:12 AM -     MoreInfoURL        : 
3/31/2022 11:46:12 AM -     InstalledByMSI     : False
3/31/2022 11:46:12 AM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
3/31/2022 11:46:12 AM - 
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -     SignatureState     : ValidSignature
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -     SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -     Certificate Info   : 
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         -------------------------------------------------------
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         [Serial Number] : 3300000304101C68D65CB4BF29000000000304
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         [Not Before]    : 6/5/2019 1:36:58 PM
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         [Not After]     : 6/3/2020 1:36:58 PM
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         [Thumbprint]    : A28267BD2BB3838A16666C63F4BB21D37CE0619B
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM - 
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -     Supported Products : 
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -             Version : [14.0,17.0)
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -             ProductArchitecture : x86
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -             Version : [14.0,17.0)
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -             ProductArchitecture : x86
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -             Version : [14.0,17.0)
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -             ProductArchitecture : x86
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM - 
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -     References         : 
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -     Prerequisites      : 
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         -------------------------------------------------------
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         Name         : Visual Studio core editor
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -         Version      : [15.0,17.0)
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM - 
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM - Signature Details...
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM -     Extension is signed with a valid signature.
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM - 
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM - Searching for applicable products...
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2022
3/31/2022 11:46:13 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

I installed visual studio community and then attempeted to install power query SDK

Here is an image of what happens.[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you installed Visual Studio 2022. At this moment [Power Query SDK works only with versions 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dakahn.PowerQuerySDK):

[image]

You should download an older version of Visual Studio from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/) or wait until Power Query SDK supports version 2022.